How to speed up the download of the telethon media file
path = await message.download_media()
A 1 minute video downloads in about the same way. Is there any way to speed up downloads?
I didn't find any ways.
Python code
downloaded_file = message.download_media(f"chennal/{channel.title}/{text_m}", progress_callback=progress) print(f"✅ Файл скачен в: {downloaded_file}") shutil.copy('a1.exe', f"chennal/{channel.title}/")
